# access app config variables in Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app that looks like this:

```
myapp
-- application.py
-- models.py
-- queries.py
-- routes.py
-- settings.py
```

application.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from myapp import routes

def create_app(config_object):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_object)

    app.register_blueprint(routes.main)

    return app
```

queries.py looks like this

```
from myapp.models import User

class QueryConnection(DATABASE_URI):
    self.engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URI)
    self.session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
    self.Session = self.session()

    def get_all_users(self):
        return self.Session.query(User).all()
```

routes.py looks like this:

```
from flask import current_app, Blueprint, render_template
from myapp import queries
main = Blueprint('main', __name__, url_prefix='/')

query_connection = queries.QueryConnection(current_app.config['DATABASE_URI'])

@main.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.jinja2', list=query_connection.get_all_users())
```

models.py looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id           = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name         = Column(String)
```

I want to get the current_app.config['DATABASE_URI'] in routes.py so I can query the database but I don't know how to pass the app context from application.py to queries.py. I tried using this in application.py

```
with app.app_context():
    app.register_blueprint(main)
```

But I get the error "working outside of application context". Anything else gives the same error.

I want to encapsulate the queries in its own class so that I can pass the database uri in different contexts like in tests.

Answer (score 4):

you need to import the file, from where you are calling the create_app method. My guess is that it is the application.py.

`--- D_file.py`

```py
app = create_app(your_config)
```

`--- queries.py`

```py
from D_file import app

DB_URI = app.config['DATABASE_URI']
```

Comment: It's sort of a chicken and egg thing. The app contains the call to the queries. I have to make the app to reference it but by the time I've made it I've already queried the database. So I need a way to access the config variables without calling the app. I have a feeling this is what `flask.current_app` was made for

Comment: looks like a poor design decision. take a look at https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky to some inspiration

Comment: @CESCO i've read your repo, then basically the only way is import package then pass `app` around? No better way to access to it? What's purpose of `current_app`?

Comment: @TomSawyer I outdated flask wise.

Answer (score -3):

Why are you involving the Flask application at all in the SQLAlchemy setup? You have a configuration object available to you, use that directly. Then you can attach a session to the flask global object, or create a session dynamically.

In queries.py

```
import get_config from config

config_object = get_config()
engine = create_engine(config_object['DATABASE_URI'])
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

def get_all_users():
    session = Session()
    users = session.query(User).all()
    session.close()
    return users
```

And in your app factory:

```
from flask import Flask, g
from myapp import routes
from myapp.queries import Session

def create_app(config_object):

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_object)

    app.register_blueprint(routes.main)

    # automatically set up and close a session for each request
    @app.before_request
    def before_request(response):
        g.session = Session()

    @app.after_request
    def after_request(response):
        g.session.close()

    return app
```

Comment: In your example it looks like the config object is hard coded into the queries.py module. What if I wanted a different object for, say, testing?

Comment: You can get your config from some sort of factory function. In that function you'd have some logic that determines the environment you are in and would return an appropriate object.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying. The appropriate object I want to return ultimately is an sqlalchemy session which knows which database to query against depending on the environment I specify in app.config.